# How to play unsecure video in AVPlayer in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I wanted to play video with URL in AVPlayerViewController. When I am using secure links (https) then video played successfully but when I am using http URLs then it just keep buffering.

[image]

Can anyone help me out here??

Comment: did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

If something works with secure URLs and not non secure URLs in iOS then you are very likely haivng issues with `App Transport Security (ATS)`.

It blocks non secure traffic. If you really must use a non secure connection, you have to configure ATS to allow the connections.

[NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloadsformedia) setting this value to true in your plist should allow you to load non secure content to play videos.

To do this, open up your `info.plist` file for your project.

- If an entry for `App Transport Security Settings` does not exist. Add it.
- Expand `App Transport Security Settings`
- Add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia` with a value of `YES`/`true`

Re-run your app and try that.